# Problems Installing Snap Store

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install Snap Store in Deepin 15.11(a Linux distro), entering the command:

```
sudo snap install snap-store
```

returns with the error message:

> error: cannot perform the following tasks:
> Mount snap "snap-store" (415) (snap "snap-store" assumes unsupported features: command-chain (try to update snapd and refresh the core snap))

I have refreshed snap using the command:

```
sudo snap refresh core
```

It doesn't seem to make any difference.

My configuration:

```
snap 2.30-5+b1
snapd 2.30-5+b1
series 16
deepin 15.11
kernel 4.15.0-29deepin-generic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your installed snapd package is out of data, even by Ubuntu 14.04 standards. rmadison interrogates the Madison services hosted by Debian and Ubuntu to determine the availability of packages. In this case we will use rmadison to search for the *snapd* package as follows:

```
sudo apt install devscripts   
rmadison -u ubuntu snapd  
rmadison -u debian snapd
```

Then visit either [Ubuntu Packages Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) or [Debian Packages Search](https://packages.debian.org/index) and search for a version of snapd >= 2.42. The Snap Store works fine even if *snap* is not installed, so you only need to update the *snapd* package. SNAP is a general purpose gene finding program suitable for both eukaryotic and prokaryotic genomes, so you can safely uninstall it with `sudo apt remove snap` if you don't need it.

A command that installs the snapd .deb package has the following form. Open the terminal, change directories with `cd` to the directory that contains the snapd .deb file that you downloaded, and type:

```
sudo apt install ./snapd_2.42.1+18.04_amd64.deb # snapd package from bionic-updates repository
```